# Using Flexbox, can I change the amount of items displayed on a row, depending on how many items are added

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, css-grid

Scenario:

Using flexbox, I'm creating a template where the number of 'cards' displayed can change from page to page. If a user adds 2, 3 or 4 cards – the layout is great.

However, if a user adds 5 cards, the layout is now less aesthetically pleasing with the 5th card alone on a new row.

Is there a way I can display up to 4 cards on a row, but if there are 5+ cards.. then the first row would display 3 cards, and the second row would display 2?

Here's a general idea of how the code would be displayed.

```
<style>
  .cards-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  
  .cards-wrapper .card {
    flex: 1 1 20%;
    margin: 10px;
  }
</style>

<div class="cards-wrapper">

  <div class="card"> </div>

  <div class="card"> </div>

  <div class="card"> </div>

  <div class="card"> </div>

  <div class="card"> </div>

</div>
```

Comment: i don't see a way arround it without using Javascript and changing the width from 20 to 33

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `nth-child` & `nth-last-child` pseudo classes.

```
.cards-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 10px;
}
.cards-wrapper .card {
    flex: 1 1 calc(25% - 10px);
}
.card:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(5),
.card:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(4),
.card:nth-child(3):nth-last-child(3) {
    flex-basis: calc(33.333% - 10px);
}
```

The trick works for 5 elements (9th would stay alone in the last row) However, this is not elegant solution. In this case I'd recommend to use CSS grid instead of flexbox.

Answer (score -1):

You can accomplish this with Bootstrap if you are able to use this.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#all-breakpoints

Bootstrap comes with the breakpoints already defined so you give it the specific class you need based off the sizing of the screen
col-lg-3 (on a large screen the column will span 3)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think you misunderstood. Bootstrap breakpoints will not help a varying number of cards per page